# List of list generation

Tags: specman

simple question :
for simplicity : struct contains only one item of type bool :

```
struct dummy_s {
    is_high : bool;
};
```

I've a matrix of struct :

```
matrix : list of list of dummy_s;
```

My intention is to have at least one list which contain number of structs which have more than 1 'is_high == TRUE'.
Whats wrong with the code i wrote :

```
keep matrix.has(it.count(it.is_high) > 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

List-pseudo-method inside list-pseudo-method is currently considered an input for the random generator - meaning, non generative.

a generative model can be:

```
matrix : list of list of dummy_s;

idx : uint;
keep idx < value(matrix.size());

keep for each in matrix {
    idx == index => it.count(it.is_high) > 1;
};
```